# Help me to complete this list

Tags: word-choice

If assuming that -:

> The ability of being 'Accessible'= `Accessibility`
>   The ability of being 'Read'= `Readability`
>   The ability of being 'Scanned'= `Scanability`

So

> The ability of being `Interacted` to/with = ?
>   The ability of being `Trusted` = ?
>   The ability of being `Navigated` = ?
>   The ability of being `Understood` = ?
>   The ability of being `Felt` (feel) = ?
>   The ability of being `Find` = ? 
>   The ability of being `Customized` = ?
>   The ability of being `Adaptive` = ?

Please tell me the appropriate words (ending with `bility`).

Answer (score 2):

- The ability of being Interacted to/with = n/a (you can say that something is interactive, or the interactive nature/quality of sth)
- The ability of being Trusted = **trustability** / trustworthiness
- The ability of being Navigated = **navigability**
- The ability of being Understood = **understandability**
- The ability of  being Felt (feel) = n/a
- The ability of being Find = **findability**
- The ability of being Customized = **customizability**
- The ability of being Adaptive = **adaptivity**/ adaptabilty

Comment: How about `sensibility` for being felt ?

Comment: It's the opposite, it's the ability to feel or perceive

Comment: How about `Interoperability` for interaction ? Also `Adaptability` ‍‍for Adaptive ?

Comment: Adaptability is ok. Interoperability has a different meaning than being interacted with; it is the ability of a system to provide services to and accept services from other systems

Comment: I think _trustworthiness_ would be preferred over of _trustability_, and I like _adaptabilty_ more than _adaptivity_. However, all four are legitimate words, so there's nothing "wrong" with your suggestions.

Comment: @J.R. Do you have any suggestion for ability of being `Felt` and `Interacted to/with`? I found `Intractability`. However, I don't know if it has a right meaning.

Comment: @Omid intractability is definitely wrong. It's the quality of being difficult to manage, hard to influence or control

Comment: What kind of "feeling" are we talking about here? Tactile sensations? Empathy? Emotion? A premonition or sixth sense? A strong opinion about something? _Feel_ is a rather flexible word with several definitions; I can feel how the ice is cold, I can feel how the sandpaper is rough, I can feel sorry that your grandmother died, I can feel exuberant that my favorite team won a championship, I can feel that it's going to rain soon, I can feel that euthanasia is wrong, and I can feel confused about which meaning of _feel_ you are asking about.

Comment: @J.R. I mean Emotion. You made a very good example about ice.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for all such words to end with "bility".
The  **ability** of being accessible is not "accessibility" but the  **degree** to which it is accessible. ( same is true for readability). Furthermore,the ability of being accessed is "accessible" and the degree to which it is accessible is "accessibility".

I can tell a few of terms for the above mentioned phrases-:
The ability of being felt-: palpability.
The ability of being trusted-: trustworthiness.

Comment: I made an assumption dude!

Comment: What assumption ? Clarify to me.

Comment: I said: If The ability of being Accessible = Accessibility

Comment: These are adjectives, I think the OP was looking for nouns

Comment: Please tell me how can their be nouns in such a question ?

Comment: The ability of doing or being something, is a noun. Having this ability is an adjective. Can you see the difference?

Comment: @Inquist being comprehensive doesn't necessarily imply being understandable